# Wrapping legacy object in IConnectableObservable

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a legacy event-based object that seems like a perfect fit for RX: after being connected to a network source, it raises events when a message is received, and may terminate with either a single error (connection dies, etc.) or (rarely) an indication that there will be no more messages. This object also has a couple projections -- most users are interested in only a subset of the messages received, so there are alternate events raised only when well-known message subtypes show up.

So, in the process of learning more about reactive programming, I built the following wrapper:

```
class LegacyReactiveWrapper : IConnectableObservable<TopLevelMessage>
{
    private LegacyType _Legacy;
    private IConnectableObservable<TopLevelMessage> _Impl;
    public LegacyReactiveWrapper(LegacyType t) 
    {
        _Legacy = t;
        var observable = Observable.Create<TopLevelMessage>((observer) => 
        {
            LegacyTopLevelMessageHandler tlmHandler = (sender, tlm) => observer.OnNext(tlm);
            LegacyErrorHandler errHandler = (sender, err) => observer.OnError(new ApplicationException(err.Message));
            LegacyCompleteHandler doneHandler = (sender) => observer.OnCompleted();

            _Legacy.TopLevelMessage += tlmHandler;
            _Legacy.Error += errHandler;
            _Legacy.Complete += doneHandler;

            return Disposable.Create(() => 
            {
                _Legacy.TopLevelMessage -= tlmHandler;
                _Legacy.Error -= errHandler;
                _Legacy.Complete -= doneHandler;
            });
        });

        _Impl = observable.Publish();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<TopLevelMessage> observer)
    {
        return _Impl.RefCount().Subscribe(observer);
    }

    public IDisposable Connect()
    {
        _Legacy.ConnectToMessageSource();
        return Disposable.Create(() => _Legacy.DisconnectFromMessageSource());
    }

    public IObservable<SubMessageA> MessageA
    {
        get
        {
            // This is the moral equivalent of the projection behavior
            // that already exists in the legacy type. We don't hook
            // the LegacyType.MessageA event directly.
            return _Impl.RefCount()
                    .Where((tlm) => tlm.MessageType == MessageType.MessageA)
                    .Select((tlm) => tlm.SubMessageA);
        }
    }

    public IObservable<SubMessageB> MessageB
    {
        get
        {
            return _Impl.RefCount()
                    .Where((tlm) => tlm.MessageType == MessageType.MessageB)
                    .Select((tlm) => tlm.SubMessageB);
        }
    }
}
```

Something about how it's used elsewhere feels... off... somehow, though. Here's sample usage, which works but feels strange. The UI context for my test application is WinForms, but it doesn't really matter.

```
// in Program.Main... 

MainForm frm = new MainForm();

// Updates the UI based on a stream of SubMessageA's
IObserver<SubMessageA> uiManager = new MainFormUiManager(frm);

LegacyType lt = new LegacyType();
// ... setup lt...

var w = new LegacyReactiveWrapper(lt);

var uiUpdateSubscription = (from msgA in w.MessageA
                            where SomeCondition(msgA)
                            select msgA).ObserveOn(frm).Subscribe(uiManager);

var nonUiSubscription = (from msgB in w.MessageB
                         where msgB.SubType == MessageBType.SomeSubType
                         select msgB).Subscribe(
                             m => Console.WriteLine("Got MsgB: {0}", m),
                             ex => Console.WriteLine("MsgB error: {0}", ex.Message),
                             () => Console.WriteLine("MsgB complete")
                         );

IDisposable unsubscribeAtExit = null;
frm.Load += (sender, e) => 
{
    var connectionSubscription = w.Connect();
    unsubscribeAtExit = new CompositeDisposable(
                               uiUpdateSubscription,
                               nonUiSubscription,
                               connectionSubscription);
};

frm.FormClosing += (sender, e) => 
{
    if(unsubscribeAtExit != null) { unsubscribeAtExit.Dispose(); }
};


Application.Run(frm);
```

This WORKS -- The form launches, the UI updates, and when I close it the subscriptions get cleaned up and the process exits (which it won't do if the LegacyType's network connection is still connected). Strictly speaking, it's enough to dispose just `connectionSubscription`. However, the explicit `Connect` feels weird to me. Since `RefCount` is supposed to do that for you, I tried modifying the wrapper such that rather than using `_Impl.RefCount` in `MessageA` and `MessageB` and explicitly connecting later, I used `this.RefCount` instead and moved the calls to `Subscribe` to the `Load` handler. That had a different problem -- the second subscription triggered another call to `LegacyReactiveWrapper.Connect`. I thought the idea behind `Publish`/`RefCount` was "first-in triggers connection, last-out disposes connection."

I guess I have three questions:

1. Do I fundamentally misunderstand `Publish`/`RefCount`?
2. Is there some preferred way to implement `IConnectableObservable<T>` that doesn't involve delegation to one obtained via `IObservable<T>.Publish`? I know you're not supposed to implement `IObservable<T>` yourself, but I don't understand how to inject connection logic into the `IConnectableObservable<T>` that `Observable.Create().Publish()` gives you. Is `Connect` supposed to be idempotent?
3. Would someone more familiar with RX/reactive programming look at the sample for how the wrapper is used and say "that's ugly and broken" or is this not as weird as it seems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you need to expose Connect directly as you have. I would simplify as follows, using `Publish().RefCount()` as an encapsulated implementation detail; it would cause the legacy connection to be made only as required. Here the first subscriber in causes connection, and the last one out causes disconnection. Also note this correctly shares a single `RefCount` across all subscribers, whereas your implementation uses a `RefCount` per message type, which isn't probably what was intended. Users are not required to Connect explicitly:

```
public class LegacyReactiveWrapper
{
    private IObservable<TopLevelMessage> _legacyRx; 

    public LegacyReactiveWrapper(LegacyType legacy)
    {
        _legacyRx = WrapLegacy(legacy).Publish().RefCount();
    }

    private static IObservable<TopLevelMessage> WrapLegacy(LegacyType legacy)
    {
        return Observable.Create<TopLevelMessage>(observer =>
        {
            LegacyTopLevelMessageHandler tlmHandler = (sender, tlm) => observer.OnNext(tlm);
            LegacyErrorHandler errHandler = (sender, err) => observer.OnError(new ApplicationException(err.Message));
            LegacyCompleteHandler doneHandler = sender => observer.OnCompleted();

            legacy.TopLevelMessage += tlmHandler;
            legacy.Error += errHandler;
            legacy.Complete += doneHandler;
            legacy.ConnectToMessageSource();

            return Disposable.Create(() =>
            {
                legacy.DisconnectFromMessageSource();
                legacy.TopLevelMessage -= tlmHandler;
                legacy.Error -= errHandler;
                legacy.Complete -= doneHandler;
            });
        });
    }

    public IObservable<TopLevelMessage> TopLevelMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return _legacyRx;
        }
    }

    public IObservable<SubMessageA> MessageA
    {
        get
        {
            return _legacyRx.Where(tlm => tlm.MessageType == MessageType.MessageA)
                            .Select(tlm => tlm.SubMessageA);
        }
    }

    public IObservable<SubMessageB> MessageB
    {
        get
        {
            return _legacyRx.Where(tlm => tlm.MessageType == MessageType.MessageB)
                            .Select(tlm => tlm.SubMessageB);
        }
    }
}
```

An additional observation is that `Publish().RefCount()` will drop the underlying subscription when it's subscriber count reaches 0. Typically I only use `Connect` over this choice when I need to maintain a subscription even when the subscriber count on the published source drops to zero (and may go back up again later). It's rare to need to do this though - only when connecting is more expensive than holding on to the subscription resource when you might not need to.

Comment: +1 for `Publish().RefCount()` as an implementation detail. Too many times I see event wrappers that don't do this by default. Rx is taking care of subscriptions for you, so make sure you're not doubling up on them by adding redundant event handlers to your legacy events! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your understanding is not entirely wrong, but you do appear to have some points of misunderstanding.

   You seem to be under the belief that multiple calls to `RefCount` on the same source IObservable will result in a shared reference count.  They do not; each instance keeps its own count.  As such, you are causing multiple subscriptions to _Impl, one per call to subscribe or call to the Message properties.

   You also may be expecting that making `_Impl` an `IConnectableObservable` somehow causes your `Connect` method to be called (since you seem surprised you needed to call Connect in your consuming code).  All `Publish` does is cause subscribers to the published object (returned from the .Publish() call) to share a single subscription to the underlying source observable (in this case, the object made from your call to Observable.Create).

   Typically, I see Publish and RefCount used immediately together (eg as `source.Publish().RefCount()`) to get the shared subscription effect described above or to make a cold observable hot without needing to call Connect to start the subscription to the original source.  However, this relies on using the same object returned from the .Publish().RefCount() for all subscribers (as noted above).
2. Your implementation of Connect seems reasonable.  I don't know of any recommendations for if Connect should be idempotent, but I would not personally expect it to be.  If you wanted it to be, you would just need to track calls to it the disposal of its return value to get the right balance.

   I don't think you need to use Publish the way you are, unless there is some reason to avoid multiple event handlers being attached to the legacy object.  If you do need to avoid that, I would recommend changing `_Impl` to a plain `IObservable` and follow the `Publish` with a `RefCount`.
3. Your `MessageA` and `MessageB` properties have potential to be a source of confusion for users, since they return an IObservable, but still require a call to Connect on the base object to start receiving messages.  I would either change them to IConnectableObservables that somehow delegate to the original Connect (at which point the idempotency discussion becomes more relevant) or drop the properties and just let the users make the (fairly simple) projections themselves when needed.

Comment: The core issue was that I misunderstood how RefCount worked. The question of idempotence was related to a possibly required workaround if it worked how I THOUGHT it worked, rather than how it actually works. You have a valid point with 3); I included them both for figuring out how the connection sharing with Publish() worked and because we have a lot of code that cares about "only A" or "only B," despite their coming up in the same stream.